# Function $f$ with $\hat{f}=0$

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

Is there a function $0\neq f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d) $ with $\hat{f}=0$?

Comment: No. $f \in L^{1}, \hat f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e.

Answer (score 3):

No, if that were the case, $f,\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Thus, the Fourier Inversion Theorem holds (see Theorem 8.26 Folland "Real Analysis"), so $f$ is almost everywhere equal to zero.